# How to keep dual screens during screensaver on Windows Surface

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, screensaver, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro-4

I've just set up a second external monitor on my work Surface. I don't use the built-in screen so I fold the keyboard up against the Surface ("close the lid").

Now, every time the screensaver starts, it goes to single-screen mode and when I get back on to the desktop, all my programs have moved onto my primary external screen, leaving my secondary screen with an empty desktop.

How can I configure Windows 10 to get my applications to stay on the screen I drag them on to?

#### EDIT

I have disabled the screens from shutting down and now I get the Windows spotlight on one screen permanently (e.g. it was on all weekend). If I lock my PC manually, it keeps the screen settings. If I am away for a while, any apps from the second screen move onto the first screen. I would think it's something to do with the Lock screen settings, but I can't see anything that would make a difference.

Comment: Disable screensaver?

Comment: @AEonAX That doesn't help. I need to lock my computer when I'm away from it, and it locks itself after some time anyway. Technically, the screensaver is set to "none".

Comment: The problem is most likely power setting related. I forget exactly how an external monitor hooks to a surface, but whatever method, it is likely being disabled to save power during standby.  The way to prevent that is to prevent standby. Being it is a tablet it has “connected” standby and may not be the typical “standby” you are thinking of. You might also be able to adjust the device’s power settings if you can find it in device manager.

Comment: Do you need screensaver that bad? or you will be good with "Windows +L" to lock the workstation option?

Comment: @user1448914 No, I don't care about the screensaver at all, but it's a work computer, so it must be locked when I'm away from it.

Comment: Ok. I suggest you disable screensaver via your power options. See link here: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2843-change-power-plan-settings-windows-10-a.html . After that see this to disable the screensaver: https://www.pntbrother.com/turn-off-screen-saver-on-windows-10-deactivating-screensaver-option/  . And finaly reboot after manipulations. Then as test try to "Windows+L" your session and see if it helps (without screensaver it should be ok) otherwise i see a problem in graphics driver provided software, maybe it needs reinstalling.